# how to install missing heroku libraries?

Tags: heroku

While using `heroku create` this error occured. I know that sasl library needs to be installed, but I don't know, how to  install it on heroku, I know to install it only on localhost.

```
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.19 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
remote:            Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:18: fatal error: sasl.h: No such file or directory
remote:             #include <sasl.h>
remote:                              ^
remote:            compilation terminated.
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote: Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Q1St2s/python-ldap/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-he61Ck-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Q1St2s/python-ldap
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shielded-beyond-8167.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-beyond-8167.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-beyond-8167.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to deploy a python application to Heroku. For Python applications on Heroku, you need to list your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file in the root of your project.

For instance, if you're running a project that requires the `requests` library, then you'd define a `requirements.txt` file that contains the following

```
requests==2.7.0
```

NOTE: You can automatically create a requirements.txt file on your laptop (typically) by running:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will automatically create a requirements.txt file for you with all of your dependencies included =)

If you're still having issues after creating a requirements.txt file, it means that you're likely trying to use a C header library that hasn't been installed on the Heroku core images -- in this case, you'll need to create a custom buildpack: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks