# Install python module psutil in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am unable to install psutil by requeriments.txt neither by logging in with heroku run bash command and using the `pip install psutil` command.

The log is very large, so, I will put the "most important" part of it:

```
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-759b4csi/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-addox7ji-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-759b4csi/psutil/
```

Can someone help me with this?
I am using python 3.6.0 and pip 9.0.1

Comment: The psutil docs say "On UNIX this requires a C compiler (e.g. gcc) installed." You need to install gcc on your Heroku instance to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't use heroku. Was hoping someone else could come explain that... but a google search for "Install gcc on heroku" yields a few results including this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213207/how-to-install-missing-heroku-libraries

Comment: Okay, maybe what I need is to use a version of psutils that is already compiled. That is what I understand in that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a new requirements and this new file was processed by the deploy tool correctly.